# How to make xclip strip newline from the output piped to it?

Tags: linux, centos, clipboard, xclip

this is the command responsible for adding a new line to the `string`

```
echo "string" | xclip -selection clipboard
```

Comment: Suggest editing the title of this question to something like 'Prevent xclip from appending newline.'  It's a great question, it was just hard to find!

Comment: Good question, thanks!

Comment: The question has been fixed. Just took some 10.5 years...

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
echo -n "string" | xclip -selection clipboard
```

I should probably have elaborated a bit.  The default for **echo** is to output the string AND a newline.  **-n** suppreses the latter.

Comment: if you wish to copy current path `echo -n $(pwd) | xclip -selection clipboard`

Comment: one improvement for previous command `echo -n ${PWD/ /\\ } | xclip -selection clipboard` backslashes white spaces

Comment: see the answer below by @rools for a more generic solution using `xclip -r`

Comment: @sgdesmet - see answers in historical context. That option didn't exist back then. 0.13, which rools references, was released **2016**, not **2013** ... I have been using `-r` for a while now.

Answer (score 34):

The more generic solution is to ignore new lines regardless of the input source. For instance, the common use case is to copy to the clipboard a path of the current directory. The command

```
pwd | xclip -selection clipboard
```

copies the new line character and this is often not what we want.
The **solution** is the following:

```
pwd | xargs echo -n | xclip -selection clipboard
```

You can create an alias to make it more convenient:

```
alias xclip='xargs echo -n | xclip -selection clipboard'
```

and from now on use:

```
pwd | xclip # copied without new line
echo "foo" | xclip # copied without new line
```

Comment: how does adding `pwd` make this "more generic"? :)

Comment: If you read carefully, you can see that the generic solution refers to "ignore new lines regardless of the input source". The pwd part is shown as an example and "common use case" why you may want to do it. The last example uses echo as well.

Comment: And what suggests to you that one wants to get rid of ALL newlines? `(pwd; pwd)| xargs echo -n | xclip -selection clipboard`

Answer (score 25):

Since version 0.13 of xclip, you have a generic way that will preserve the inner new lines with the option **r** or **rmlastnl**.

So you will have:

```
pwd | xclip -r # copied without new line
echo "foo" | xclip -r # copied without new line
ps | xclip -r # copied without the last new line!
```

Comment: Requires version 0.13 though

Comment: Thanks. I will add that in my answer.

Comment: the `-r` did the trick fro me. would have helped if i fully read the man

Comment: It's been a while since xclip 0.13. This should be the accepted answer and people should update.